# mysql concat function with no selection of columns

Tags: mysql

I was reading about the CHAR and VARCHAR datatypes in the MySql manual and came across a piece of code that I did not understand:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE vc (v VARCHAR(4), c CHAR(4));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO vc VALUES ('ab ', 'ab ');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONCAT('(', v, ')'), CONCAT('(', c, ')') FROM vc;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| CONCAT('(', v, ')') | CONCAT('(', c, ')') |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| (ab )               | (ab)                |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

The CONCAT function description is pretty simple:

> Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments.

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('My', 'S', 'QL');
        -> 'MySQL'
```

I still don't see how `SELECT CONCAT('(', v, ')'), CONCAT('(', c, ')') FROM vc;` results in the output table above. There is no selection of columns from what I can see.

Comment: `v` and `c` are column names in the table.

Answer (score 2):

In concat any parameter can be string OR column name. So:

```
SELECT CONCAT('(', v, ')'), CONCAT('(', c, ')') FROM vc;
```

uses column `v` and column `c` values to create string.